# Adding an XMLNode below a specific node

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here is my XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Projects xmlns="urn:projects-schema">
    <Project>
        <Name>Project1</Name>
        <Images>
            <Image Path="D:/abc.jpg"></Image>
        </Images>
    </Project>       
</Projects>
```

1. I want to be able to Add a new Project Node though my code
2. And I want to be able to Create a new Image Node given a the Project Name

For the first task I have this so far:

```
try
{
    var filename = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Projects.xml");
    var doc = new XmlDocument();

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
    {
        if (!ProjectExists(projectName))
        {
            doc.Load(filename);
            var root = doc.DocumentElement;
            var newElement = doc.CreateElement("Project");
            root.AppendChild(newElement);

            root = doc.DocumentElement;
            newElement = doc.CreateElement("Name");
            var textNode = doc.CreateTextNode(projectName);

            root.LastChild.AppendChild(newElement);
            root.LastChild.LastChild.AppendChild(textNode);

            doc.Save(filename);
        }
        else
            throw new ApplicationException("Project already exists");
        doc = null;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

But I am struggling for the second part. This is what I have so far:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(projectFilename))
{
    doc.Load(projectFilename);
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

    XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsManager.AddNamespace("prj", "urn:projects-schema");

    root = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::prj:Project[prj:Name='" + projectName + "']", nsManager);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why is your post tagged with LINQ to XML when you're not using LINQ to XML? (That would be `XDocument`, `XElement` etc.)

Comment: Jon Skeet unbelievable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XElement projects = XElement.Parse (
@"<Projects xmlns='urn:projects-schema'>
    <Project>
        <Name>Project1</Name>
        <Images>
            <Image Path='D:/abc.jpg'></Image>
        </Images>
    </Project>       
</Projects>");
```

For Task 1, this can be done as follows:

```
projects.LastNode.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("Project", 
                                 new XElement("Name", "Project2"),
                                 new XElement("Images",
                                    new XElement("Image", "", new XAttribute("Path", "C:/abc.jpg"))
                                 )));
```

Task 2:

```
projects.Descendants("Name")
    .Where(x => x.Value == projectName).FirstOrDefault()
    .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("Images",
                       new XElement("Image", "", new XAttribute("Path", "C:/def.jpg"))
                    )
                );
```

**EDIT**: To check if an Images element exists and add a child Image element with an attribute to it

```
projects.Descendants("Project")
    .Where(x => x.Elements("Images").Any())
    .Descendants("Images").FirstOrDefault()
    .Add(new XElement("Image", "", new XAttribute("Path", "D:/xyz.jpg")));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply chirdam. Thats does add an Images element and then an Image element with an attribute. Now, the next time, I want to check if the Images element is already created, and if so, I want to just add an Image element with the attribute. How do I check if against a Project->Name element, IMAGES node exists? Thanks

Comment: If this answers your original question then please consider accepting it as an answer and create a separate question for the follow-up

Comment: @Jinish I have edited the answer to include the query where it checks to see if there is any Images element by way of `.Where(x => x.Elements("Images").Any())`, if so add a child Image element with an attribute using the `.Add()` method on the first or default element found.